# Lifecycle of publish Google Apps Script Add-ons?

Tags: google-apps-script

If I publish a Google Apps Script addon for Google Sheets, can I later,

- unpublish? does this remove the add-on for users that had installed it?
- update it? does this update the add-on for users that have installed it, or do they need to take some action to update it?

(I'm nearly certain from [these docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) that I can update & unpublish an add-on; I'm mostly unsure about the side effects of doing so.)

Answer (score 2):

If you unpublish a script it is removed from the end user.

If you update the add-on it auto updates for all your installed users. If your OAuth scopes change for the add-on during your update the end user will be re-prompted to authorize the add-on.